# What should i do to access my static resource with express-jwt？

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
//code 1

app.use(jwt({
    secret:'1'   
}).unless({
    path: ['/api/user/login','/api/user/sign']
}));
```

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

App start on 8889 port,if i delete code 1,i can access my static resource by localhost:8889/upload/x.png,but if the code1 exsit,i cant access the static resource.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of express middleware are importance.
Put `code 1` after you set static resource:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(jwt({
    secret:'1'   
}).unless({
    path: ['/api/user/login','/api/user/sign']
}));
```